# Parse XML to retrieve multiple values of same tag

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am new to XPath and XML. I am trying to retrieve values of a particular tag from tag. That particular tag in following tree structure

```
<article>
<front>
<article-meta>
<supplementary-material id="SM2379">
<caption><title>arg_3.docx</title></caption>
</supplementary-material>
<supplementary-material id="SM2375">
<caption><title>arg_2.docx</title></caption>
</supplementary-material>
<supplementary-material id="SM2373">
<caption><title>Sulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.docSulental_material.doc</title></caption>
</supplementary-material>
</article-meta>
</front>
</article>
```

I want to retrieve all '**title**' tag in this sample file along with '**id**' of parent tag. As I need to add to existing functionality I have some limitation like use jdom, can use xpath etc

Any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should first show your code and explain the concrete problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to achieve what you're trying to do if the nodes are built up straight like they are in your example.

You'll have to

- Parse the xml-file with whatever you have to use (jdom)
- Use an XPath query to retrieve the **title** nodes. (`//title` will do in your case)
- Get the `ID` of the grandparent element

These tasks should be easy enough to handle!

---

In addition to the comment:

The code provided by you:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList n1 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("article/front/article-meta/supplementary-material/caption/title", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int k = 0; k < n1.getLength();k++)
{
    System.out.println(n1.item(k).getNodeName()+" : "+n1.item(k).getTextContent());
}
```

works just fine. But the code you provided had some **UTF-8 issues** in my IDE

Comment: Can you please share sample code for it as code which i have written does working. javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
     org.w3c.dom.NodeList n1 = (org.w3c.dom.NodeList) xpath.evaluate("article/front/article-meta/supplementary-material/caption/title", xmlDocument, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET);

     for (int k = 0; k < n1.getLength(); k++) {
       System.out.println(n1.item(k).getNodeName()+" 11 "+n1.item(k).getTextContent());
     }

Comment: When i am using this code then "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown error in XPath." Exception is coming.